# ¿como validar campos vacios de un input de una misma clase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

tengo una consulta:

Tengo 5 `input` y quiero que me muestre solo los que tienen valor los demás que se eliminen.

Aquí esta mi código pero el último valor no lo elimina no se porque no lo hace.

```
<body>
    Nombre 1<input type="text" class="textbox" value="abcd"><br>
    Nombre 2<input type="text" class="textbox"><br>
    Nombre 3<input type="text" class="textbox" value="efgh"><br>
    Nombre 4<input type="text" class="textbox"><br>
    Nombre 5<input type="text" class="textbox">

    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var input = $("body").find("input");
            console.log(input.length);
            for (let i = 1; i <= input.length; i++) {
                if ($(".textbox:eq('"+i+"')").val() == "") {

                    $(".textbox:eq('"+i+"')").remove();
                }

            }


        });


    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Revisa los límites que estás usando en tu bucle `for`. Deben ir desde 0 hasta `input.length - 1`. Ese es el problema. Saludos

Comment: Aun así no funciona

Answer (score 1):

La verdad no entiendo el porqué usas lo siguiente:

```
$(".textbox:eq('"+i+"')")
```

Cuando podrías usar:

```
input.eq(i)
```

Una forma de lograr lo que intentas sería de la siguiente forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const input = $("body").find("input");
  for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input.eq(i).hasClass("textbox") && input.eq(i).val() === "") {
      input.eq(i).remove();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    Nombre 1<input type="text" class="textbox" value="abcd"><br>
    Nombre 2<input type="text" class="textbox"><br>
    Nombre 3<input type="text" class="textbox" value="efgh"><br>
    Nombre 4<input type="text" class="textbox"><br>
    Nombre 5<input type="text" class="textbox">
</body>
```

Como puedes ver realizo 2 comprobaciones, la primera para saber si el elemento es de la clase `textbox` y la segunda para saber si su valor es nulo.

Siempre es buena práctica realizar la comprobación usando el operador estricto `===`.

No sé si realmente es lo que intentas lograr, me parece que si.

Uno de los detalles de usar lo que haces así:

```
$(".textbox:eq('"+i+"')")
```

es que el valor de `i` lo estás coaccionando a ser tipo `String`, pero el método [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/:eq/) de Jquery espera un tipo entero. No estoy totalmente seguro que sea esto el causante del fallo, pero tiene toda la pinta.

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.